# Acting on two different Exceptions in one catch block

Tags: .net, exception

Is there a way to catch two different exceptions and process them in one catch block in .NET?

I'm thinking of something like

```
try {} 
catch(OverflowException ex1, FormatException ex2) 
{
}
```

I know I can use functions to reuse redundant logic in my catch blocks but I'm still curious as to whether a shorthand method exists for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No shorthand method exists. From §B.2.5 of the [C# 3.0 specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx), the grammar describes how a specific catch clause may only have a single `class-type` and an optional `identifier`:

```
try-statement:
    try   block   catch-clauses
    try   block   finally-clause
    try   block   catch-clauses   finally-clause

catch-clauses:
    specific-catch-clauses   general-catch-clauseopt
    specific-catch-clausesopt   general-catch-clause

specific-catch-clauses:
    specific-catch-clause
    specific-catch-clauses   specific-catch-clause

specific-catch-clause:
    catch   (   class-type   identifieropt   )   block

general-catch-clause:
    catch   block
```

Is there a reason you can't catch Exception and use that?

Comment: Code analysis tools compain when catching the generic Exception type.  No real reason. I just want to know if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 1):

You could derive both OverflowException and FormatException from a common base and catch the base.

```
try {} 
catch(exceptionBase ex1) 
{
}
```

See [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_15.10_The_try_statement) for quite a bit more nuts-and-bolts information about try/catch/finally blocks.

Comment: OverflowException and FormatException are built-in exceptions so that's not an option. I've considered this for custom exceptions though.

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge its not possible.

you can try

```
try {} 
catch(Exception ex) 
{
if (ex is OverflowException )
{
 //do this
}
else if(ex is FormatException )
{
 //do this
}
}
```

Comment: I think you mean to say `if (ex is OverflowException || ex is FormatException)` because a construct already exists to handle this case, i.e. multiple `catch` blocks.